# Is a topological sort required here?

Tags: design, database-design, orm, sorting

Say you are writing an ORM like entity framework. You write basic POCO, and then let entity framework do the job of creating equivalent structures in the database according to those objects.

This can get hard if those objects have foreign key relationships. Theoretically speaking we would need some sorting in order to determine which database object to create first. This was my initial thought.

Later it dawned on me that, when we compose entities in code, wouldn't "we" normally write it in a sequence that, in the end, is sorted correctly? Or is there a case where I have to assume sorting is necessary?

Comment: Why not just 1. create all tables without foreign keys 2. update tables with foreign keys

Comment: If you need to fully create a table in one go, topological sorting may help you figure out the right order to do it in, taking foreign key constraints into account. However, if you have some circular references, then topological sort won't help you. Instead, do what @Euphoric commented, construct all the tables without the foreign keys, and add them as a second step.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/deostroll/jsmd/blob/dev/tests/data/sample7.js) is javascript code that models a small part of a northwind database. Whatever way, I write this, I know all entities end up topologically sorted. (Provided the javascript compiles and is valid). But is there some case where this won't be true?